# My dynamically-retrieved choice in my Angular FormBuilder form is saving as an object, not a value

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angular-formbuilder

I'm building a form which is retrieving a list of values from Cloud Firestore along some other choices, putting them into a dropdown menu, and upon submission is creating a new document.

The options are presenting in the dropdown form, but when I submit it, all the static/local information is being passed, but the value that was retrieved from the database is only returning the object.

How do I specify the field on the object?

`component.html`

```
  <select class="custom-select" (change)="changeProperty($event)" formControlName="meter">
  <option value="" disabled>Choose</option>
  <option *ngFor="let property of propertyList | async" [ngValue]="meter">{{property.meter}}</option>
</select>
```

`component.ts` (edited to just show relevant data)

```
public newLeak: FormGroup;
propertyList: Observable<any>;


  constructor(
    private db: AngularFirestore,
    public fb: FormBuilder,    
  ) { }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.propertyList = this.db.collection('meters').valueChanges().pipe(map(data => data.map(d => d)));
    this.addNewLeak(); 
  }

  addNewLeak() {
    this.newLeak = this.fb.group({
      meter:[''],
    })  
  }

  changeProperty(e) {
    this.meter.setValue(e.target.value, {
      onlySelf: true
    })
  }

  get meter() {
    return this.newLeak.get('meter');
  }


  ResetForm() {
    this.newLeak.reset();
  }  

submitNewLeak() {
console.log(this.newLeak.value);
    this.db.collection('meters').doc(this.newLeak.value.meter).collection('leaks').doc(this.newLeak.value.date).set({technician: this.newLeak.value.user}, {merge: true});
    this.db.collection('meters').doc(this.newLeak.value.meter).collection('leaks').doc(this.newLeak.value.date).collection('apartments').doc(this.newLeak.value.apartment).set(this.newLeak.value);
    this.ResetForm();
   };

}
```

In short, everything is working fine from the UI, and it is submitting the form to the database, but it is sending an object instead of a value. (I would like to either access the `id` field or the `meter` field on the object.)

Thank you.

Comment: what it gives when you run `console.log(this.newLeak.value);` ?

Comment: What is input format now and what you are exactly expecting can you mention

Comment: @JameerKhan `{meter: "4: Object", address: "123 Gumdrop Lane", apartment: "1234", location: "Landscaping", intensity: "High", …} `

Comment: @SoumyaGangamwar `property.meter` just a 5-digit string: eg `"54321"`

Comment: use `<option [ngValue]="meter.meter">`

Comment: @Eliseo Thank you! I did `[ngValue]="property.meter"` and it is now returning `28: 54321` (which is the position of the meter in the `map`). Is there a way to return just the `54321` or, is the right move to just parse it out?

Comment: you can use `[ngValue]="meter.meter.split(':')[1]"` or add a new propertie to your meter using some like `this.meter.forEach(x=>x.lastValue=x.meter.split(':')[1]` and use meter.lastValue

Comment: @Eliseo actually -- I just tried and found out something really weird. `[ngValue]="property.meter"` returns `28: 54321` and `[value]="property.meter"` returns `54321`. Thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON.stringify` at the time of data save -

```js
this.db.collection('meters').doc(this.newLeak.value.meter).collection('leaks').doc(this.newLeak.value.date).collection('apartments').doc(this.newLeak.value.apartment).set(JSON.stringify(this.newLeak.value));  // use JSON.stringify method here
```

Comment: when I use JSON.stringify I receive `"28: Object"`(which is the position of that `meter` on the `map`). I also tried to change the `.pipe(map(data => data.map(d => d.meter)))` on the `component.ts` and `{{property}}` on the `component.html`, which looks exactly the same, and returns the same `console.log`. BTW, it's more important that I'm able to get the `meter` name for the `.doc(this.newLeak.value.meter)` portion. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

With @Eliseo's help I figured out the solution:

`component.html`

```
<select class="custom-select" (change)="changeProperty($event)" formControlName="meter">
<option value="" disabled>Choose</option>
<option *ngFor="let property of propertyList | async" [value]="property.meter">{{ property.meter }}</option>
```

After following his suggestion about adding the `.meter` to the `[ngValue]`, I discovered that using `[ngValue]` actually prepends the array location to the string: `28: 54321`, and when I changed it to `[value]="property.meter"` I was able to get the clean `meter` name of `54321`, with no additional parsing of any sort.